# Caching oracle table data into Elastic search DB effectively

Tags: java, spring, oracle, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

Best approach to cache the oracle data into Elastic search DB in Java
The Oracle DB is the master data with millions of records and need be searched based on search text. so need to use ES cache to get the performance.

Now i am checking to see **best way** to do the sync between oracle DB and ES DB.

[image: custom]

Comment: I just implemented something like this(POC) - to replace Oracle Text index with ES. Shareplex(commercial product) performs logical data replication from Oracle into Kafka stream. Then a simple Java app reads messages from Kafka and stores them into ES. The delay is minimal. PS: Shareplex is something like GoldenGate for BigData (but cheaper)

Comment: i currently used RecursiveAction and ForkJoinPool to do the pool copy.

Comment: use https://hibernate.org/search/ you will thank me later :)

Answer (score 0):

i did the the above system. And people are welcome to suggest the change

i used spring JPA with hibernate on oracle and
Spring JPA with ES

pseudo code

1. check if the id is present in ES repository
2. if present
   return the Page
3. if missing

   3.1  fetch from oracle db using Oracle Repository

   3.2  user java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction to copy the data from oracle repo to ES repo and use ForkJoinPool to invoke the recursive action . (or your could do your own custom logic to do this in a multi thread way)

   3.3  return the Page (one trouble to tackle the above step 3.2 is using daemon thread)
4. end

Please post your suggestion on improvement of this.

Comment: And need keep update fresh record in crud operation...